Importing a module as a dependency in another module makes its autowired beans fail
this is my parent module:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>iot-gateway-admin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>iot-gateway-admin</name>
    <description>iot-gateway-admin</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>iot-gateway-admin-controller</module>
        <module>iot-gateway-admin-dao</module>
        <module>iot-gateway-admin-model</module>
        <module>iot-gateway-admin-service</module>
        <module>iot-gateway-admin-device-manager</module>
    </modules>
.....the rest

device manager module's pom:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>iot-gateway-admin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>device-manager</artifactId>
    <name>device-manager</name>
    <description>device-manager</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example2.iot</groupId>
            <artifactId>example2-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${com.example2.iot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example2.iot</groupId>
            <artifactId>modbus-interworking</artifactId>
            <version>${com.example2.iot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...the rest

service module pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>iot-gateway-admin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>iot-gateway-admin-service</artifactId>
    <version>${example-admin.version}</version>
    <name>iot-gateway-admin-service</name>
    <description>iot-gateway-admin-service</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>device-manager</artifactId>
            <version>${example-admin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...other dependencies
    </dependencies>
</project>

and this is an impl in device manager:
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ModbusEquipmentManagerImpl implements ModbusEquipmentManager {

    @Autowired
    private ModbusProxy modbusProxy;

when i import device manager into the service using
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>device-manager</artifactId>
            <version>${example-admin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

the autowiring suddenly fails and i get "Could not autowire. No beans of 'ModbusProxy' type found. ". when i remove it from service, the error goes away. there's nothing wrong with ModbusProxy itself, however, it's from another microservice that's installed and it's fetched from the local repository .

By the way, it's the same way when i add it as a dependency to any of the other modules

In your device-manager do you use the spring-boot-maven-plugin in your pom file?
